# AutoMapper: Mapping Tuple to Tuple

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper in my ASP.NET MVC4 project. I have a problem when mapping 2 class Question and QuestionViewModel. Here my two model classes:

```
   public class Question
    {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Content { get; set; }
      public Tuple<int, int> GetVoteTuple()
       {
         "some code here"
       }
    }

   public class QuestionViewModel
    {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Content { get; set; }
      public Tuple<int, int> VoteTuple { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my controller code :

```
   public class QuestionController: Controller 
    {
       public ActionResult Index(int id)
         {

            Question question = Dal.getQuestion(id);
            Mapper.CreateMap<Question, QuestionViewModel>()
                .ForMember(p => p.VoteTuple,
                m => m.MapFrom(
                s => s.GetVoteTuple()
            ));

            QuestionViewModel questionViewModel =
                        Mapper.Map<Question, QuestionViewModel>(question);

            return View(questionViewModel);

          }
     }
```

When I run this code the `VoteTuple` property in `QuestionViewModel` has null value. How can I map 2 class with Tuple property ?

Thanks.

Comment: What version are you using? Also, the MapFrom piece isn't necessary, AutoMapper automaps GetFoo() -> Foo (method called Get to property without the Get).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapping from Tuple to Tuple is not possible by default through Automapper, because Tuple doesn't have setter properties (they can only be initialized through the constructor).

You have 2 options:

1) Create a custom resolver for Automapper and then use the .ResolveUsing method in the  mapping config: `.ForMember(p => p.VoteTuple, m => m.ResolveUsing<CustomTupleResolver>())`

2) Map to a properties / a class instead, like this:

```
public class QuestionViewModel
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Content { get; set; }
  public int VoteItem1 { get; set; }
  public int VoteItem2 { get; set; }
}
```

And then:

```
.ForMember(p => p.VoteItem1, m => m.MapFrom(g => g.Item1))
.ForMember(p => p.VoteItem2, m => m.MapFrom(g => g.Item2))
```

You don't really need to use Tuple in your view model, so I'd recommend the 2nd option.

**Edit**:

I see that you've updated your code so that GetVoteTuple() is a function, not a property. In that case, you could easily adapt the code like this:

```
.ForMember(p => p.VoteItem1, m => m.MapFrom(g => g.GetVoteTuple().Item1))
.ForMember(p => p.VoteItem2, m => m.MapFrom(g => g.GetVoteTuple().Item2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `CreateMap` call is incorrect:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Question, QuestionViewModel>()
    .ForMember(p => p.VoteTuple,
        m => m.MapFrom(
        s => s.GetVoteTuple()
//-----------^
     ));
```

Comment: Thanks you Andrew, I change 'question' -> 's' but it still has null value.

Comment: @user3286476: Can you show the implementation of `GetVoteTuple()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ResolveUsing` instead of `MapFrom` (and use the generic `s` argument in your lambda instead of the local variable reference:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<Question, QuestionViewModel>()
            .ForMember(p => p.VoteTuple,
            m => m.ResolveUsing(
            s => s.GetVoteTuple()
        ));
```

`MapFrom` is used to map *properties* directly.  Since you're wanting to "map" from the result of a function call, `ResolveFrom` is more appropriate.

Also, you should only call `CreateMap` once in your application, typically that's done in `Application_Start` in `global.asax`

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<Question, QuestionViewModel>()
                .ForMember(p => p.VoteTuple,op=>op.MapFrom(v=>new Tuple<int,int>(v.GetVoteTuple.Item1,v.GetVoteTuple.Item2)));
```